# Image not being displayed from a php file

Tags: php

Following is the piece of code which is not working:-

```
img src="/old/datagraphsarchive.php?graphing=1&amp;streamCode=ATQ_CALD&amp;date=2008-07-04&amp;iver=1"
```

Is there any problem with the way I have specified the image source?

Comment: Can you add more code?

Comment: If `datagraphsarchive.php` is working as expected and returns a valid image, then yes this should work.

Comment: What about the `<>` characters around the tag? Why didn't you copy them to SO?

Comment: When I added it said I am not supposed to add an image until I have 10 credits.

Comment: What happens when you simply call "/old/datagraphsarchive.php?graphing=1&amp;streamCode=ATQ_CALD&amp;date=2008-07-04&amp;iver=1" - Does it load the file?

Answer (score 0):

This is potentially loading the php file directly instead of as a script. Try using the full external URL in your `img` src and see if it works.

For example: http://www.yoursite.com/old/datagraphsarchive.php?graphing=1&streamCode=ATQ_CALD&date=2008-07-04&iver=1

If that works, I've yet to actually determine what causes the phenomenon, but you can use the full external url!

If neither work, then your problem lies in the way you're generating your image from the `graphsarchive.php` file. Ensure you are setting the correct `Content-Type` headers and writing the binary stream to the page content, like so:

```
$file = 'myimage.jpg';
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
readfile($file);
```